# Truncate a floating point number without rounding up

Tags: ruby, math, floating-point, decimal, precision

I have a floating point number that I want to truncate to 3 places but I don't want to round up.

For example, convert `1.0155555555555555` to `1.015` (not `1.016`).

How would I go about doing this in Ruby?

Comment: What should happen for negative numbers, e.g. -1.01555 ?

Comment: @MarkByers For what I am doing, the number will never be negative.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you have a `float`, try this:

```
(x * 1000).floor / 1000.0
```

Result:

```
1.015
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Rr70z)

Comment: Not always, for example (128.653 * 1000)  / 1000.0 => 128.652 # doesn't work - because the multiplied value comes out as 128652.999999

Comment: This is not an answer because it relies on floor rounding, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 25):

You can also convert to a BigDecimal, and call truncate on it.

```
1.237.to_d.truncate(2).to_f # will return 1.23
```

Comment: Thanks, Sid.  That's exactly the approach I was looking for.

Comment: Cheers @ElliotLarson!

Comment: It fails on `59.99999999999999999999.to_d.truncate(2).to_f`, returns `60.0`!!

Comment: @Anwar That's because precision is too fine for a regular Float. Even `59.99999999999999999999.inspect` is "60.0". So the conversion happens prior to `to_d`.

Comment: Hey guys, there's a precision glitch when integer portion is big enough. `111111111.9999999.to_d.truncate(2).to_f` is `111111112.0`. See my hacked version below. Cheers!

Comment: @Anwar I would recommend reading: floating point arithmetic for computer processors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Answer (score 19):

Since **ruby 2.4** [`Float#truncate`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Float.html#method-i-truncate) method takes as an optional argument a number of decimal digits:

```
1.0155555555555555.truncate(3)
# => 1.015
```

Answer (score 7):

Multiply by a thousand, floor, divide by a thousand, making sure to do a float division.

```
(x * 1000).floor / 1000.0
```

Or, in Ruby 1.9.2, using a version of round that wasn't available in earlier versions,

```
(x - 0.0005).round(3)
```

Comment: Don't you just love doubles... 
pry(main)> (1.0155555 * 1000).floor / 1000.0
=> 1.015 # works fine
pry(main)> (128.653 * 1000).floor / 1000.0
=> 128.652 # doesn't work - because the multiplied value comes out as 128652.999999

Answer (score 3):

sid's answer is fine but it misses the first requirement and thus fails Anwar's test. the requirement there is we must start raw so that ruby does not convert the number readily. and to start raw as raw gets is to use a plain string, so

```
> "59.99999999999999999999".to_d.truncate(2)
=> #BigDecimal:55a38a23cd68,'0.5999E2',18(45)>
> "59.99999999999999999999".to_d.truncate(2).to_s
=> "59.99"
> "59.99999999999999999999".to_d.truncate(2).to_f
=> 59.99
```

just sharing this now, since i just encountered this problem myself today : )

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on a brilliant BigDecimal trick by @SidKrishnan, but can also handle bigger floats without faltering on precision issues.

```
# Truncate a floating-point value without rounding up.
#
#   trunc_float(1.999, 2)   # => 1.99
#   trunc_float(1.999, 0)   # => 1.0
#
# @param value [Float]
# @param precision [Integer]
# @return [Float]
def trunc_float(value, precision)
  BigDecimal(value.to_s).truncate(precision).to_f
end

#--------------------------------------- Test

describe ".trunc_float" do
  def call(*args)
    trunc_float(*args)
  end

  it "generally works" do
    [
      [[1, 0], 1.0],
      [[1.999, 4], 1.999],
      [[1.999, 3], 1.999],
      [[1.999, 2], 1.99],
      [[1.999, 1], 1.9],
      [[1.999, 0], 1.0],
      [[111111111.9999999, 3], 111111111.999],
      [[1508675846.650976, 6], 1508675846.650976],
    ].each do |input, expected|
      output = call(*input)
      expect([input, output]).to eq [input, expected]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw the more 'computational' way of doing this is not within the answers.  You can consider using the method below.

This will also work in other programming languages, like C/ Java/ Python etc. (however the casting syntax would be different).

```rb
q = 1.0155555555555555
(q * 1000).to_i / 1000.0
=> 1.015
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few options - some of them are mentioned in the answers above, but not all.

You can use `.floor(n)`

```
# Returns the largest number less than or equal to
# float with a precision of n digits decimal digits (default: 0).
# -> basically its rounding down the number

> 1.0155555555555555.floor(3)
1.015
```

You can use `.truncate(n)`

```
# Returns float truncated to a precision 
# of n digits decimal digits (default: 0).

> 1.0155555555555555.truncate(3)
=> 1.015
```

You can use `.round(n, :truncate)` (Only on `BigDecimal` not on `float`)

```
> 1.0155555555555555.to_d.round(3, :truncate).to_f
=> 1.015
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using regex, since ruby/rails have precision limit.

-- first convert the number to string and then do following -

input = "114.99999999999999999999"

input[/\d+.\d/]

114.99