# Float number format without rounding in ruby

Tags: ruby, floating-point, format

There is a float number `num = 22.0098`. How can I format it to limit 3 digits after floating point? I tried `sprintf('%.3f',num)` but return is `22.010`, I need `22.009` though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to truncate a floating point number without rounding up in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106677/how-to-truncate-a-floating-point-number-without-rounding-up-in-ruby)

Comment: The above link also includes a simple solution: `sprintf('%.3f', num - 0.0005)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, unlike [`Float#round`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Float.html#method-i-round), `Float#floor` does not accept an amount of digits. The below code implements the desired behaviour.

```
def floor_float input, digits = 3
  input.divmod(10 ** -digits).first / (10 ** digits).to_f  
end
```

This might be used as monkey patch:

```
class Float
  def floor_ext digits = 3
    self.divmod(10 ** -digits).first / (10 ** digits).to_f  
  end 
end
22.0098.floor_ext
#⇒ 22.009
```

Probably more succinct variant as suggested by @Stefan:

```
class Float
  def floor_ext digits = 3
    div(10 ** -digits).fdiv(10 ** digits)
  end 
end
22.0098.floor_ext
#⇒ 22.009
```

Or, one might deal with strings explicitly:

```
i, f = 22.0098.to_s.split('.')
#⇒ [ "22", "0098" ]
[i, f[0..2]].join('.')
#⇒ "22.009"
```

Comment: You can express it more succinct: `input.div(10 ** -digits).fdiv(10 ** digits)`. Also, within `Float`, you can omit `self`.

Comment: Approximately OK, but strictly speaking, there are about 367 IEEE double precision between 0 and 1 that will be incorrectly rounded up to 3 digits. For example, the nearest Float to 0.009 is less than 9/1000 (it is exactly 0.00899999999999999931998839741709161899052560329437255859375), though it will be floor-printed "0.009". Since the shortest decimal representation to this Float is "0.009", this might appear as the correct answer and fit OP requirements, but it's technically not.

Answer (score 8):

I can think of using bigdecimal. Not sure though if its an overkill:

```
require 'bigdecimal'   
BigDecimal::new("22.0098").truncate(3).to_f
#=> 22.009
```

Comment: Sorry, using gems are not allowed by requirements

Comment: @NodirNasirov its not a third-party gem. [`BigDecimal`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) is a Ruby built-in support.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many digits there are in the integer part, you can format it as a string:

```
sprintf("%.6s", num)
# => "22.009"
```

In general, you can adjust the `6` depending on the size of `num`.

Comment: I don't know the number of digits in the integer part